# Not able to change the redirect path using ngnix on docker

Tags: nginx, docker

I am unable to change the redirect path while using ngnix on docker. I am explaining my code below.

```
location / {
        # rewrite ^/static(.*) /$1 break;
        # root /static;
        return 301 $scheme://$host:$server_port/site;
        alias /app/static/angular;
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    location /node {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
```

here my requirement is when user will type only `https://localhost:port/` on browser then the URl should be changed to `https:localhost:port/site` on browser and same index page will be loaded.any help will be more appreciated.

Comment: You need to configure this on the service running on port `port`.

Comment: Can you please post your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your nginx is listening on Port 80/443.

Your nginx can't magically handle requests that come directly to the port 8081. You need to configure this directly on the service that is listening on port 8081.

Comment: Its running on 443. and after building image I running command `docker run -d --rm --name ubot-ubuntu --dns 64.104.128.236 --dns 72.163.128.140 --dns 64.104.76.247 -p 9999:443 --env API_PORT=9999 --env USER_NAME=subhrajp --env USER_PASS=subhrajp ubot-ubuntu:latest` to start container where user will run `https://localhost:9999/` from the url.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how this is related to the answer.